Как правильно? Мы постелИм или мы постелЕм?

Интернет дает два разных ответа

Правильно: постелем
Пояснение

Ответы на вопросы нужно искать или уточнять в словарях (это проверенные источники), а также на сайте Грамота.ру

Существуют два глагола стлать и стелить, которые отличаются по стилю: стлать (основной вариант) и стелить (разг.). Глагол постелить —  это сов.вид для глагола стелить.

Глагол стлать —  1-ое спряжение. Все глаголы изменяются также  по образу 1-го спряжения, в том числе глагол постелить.

Грамота.ру


ОТВЕТ.
Есть два однокоренных глагола: стлать и стелить. Если судить по инфинитивам, то первый должен относиться к первому спряжению, а второй — ко второму. Инфинитив стлать так себя и ведет: он изменяется, как глагол первого спряжения (стелю, стелешь, стелет, стелем, стелете, стелют), и образует соответствующее причастие стелющий.
Глагол стелить должен изменяться, как глагол второго спряжения. Но стелить совпадает по значению со стлать (разница между ними стилистическая).
Два ряда форм, различающихся только гласной в окончании, избыточны, поэтому в орфографии признаются допустимыми только формы первого спряжения (стелю, стелешь, стелет и т. д., стелющий), фактически являющиеся формами глагола стлать, и не допускаются формы стелишь, стелит и т. д., фактически являющиеся формами глагола стелить.
При обучении орфографии проще сказать, что глагол стелить является исключением и относится к первому спряжению. И от стлать, и от стелить образуется форма стели́мый.
СЛОВАРИ
СТЕЛИТЬ. Большой толковый словарь русского языка.
СТЕЛИТЬ, стелю, стелешь; стеленный; -лен, -а, -о; нсв. (св. постелить). что. Разг. = Стлать. С. скатерть. С. лён. С. постель.
ПОСТЕЛИТЬ, -стелю, -стелешь; прич. страд. прош. постеленный, -лен, -а, -о; сов., перех. (несов. стелить). разг. То же, что постлать. Милая спросила: — Крутит ли метель? Затопить бы печку, постелить постель. Есенин, Голубая кофта. Синие глаза. Малый академический словарь
ДОСТЕЛИТЬ.  Русский орфографический словарь:
достелить, достелю, достелет; прош. -ил, -ила
ПОДСТЕЛИТЬ
Русский орфографический словарь:
подстелить, подстелю, подстелет; прош. -ил, -ила
Толковый словарь Ефремовой. СТЛАТЬ несов. перех. 1. Расстилать по поверхности. || перен. Распространять по поверхности или низко над поверхностью. 2. Раскладывать, расстилать для беления, сушки и т.п. 3. Делать покрытие, настил, укладывая плотно в ряд доски, бревна и т.п.
